# WPF - Add buttons in chess-like layout

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to add Buttons to my WPF Window when a button is pressed. I want a square of 8x8 buttons that is placed from the top left corner. I tried this code:

```
int left = 20, top = 20;
        for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++)
            {
                fields[x, y] = new Button();
                fields[x, y].Margin = new Thickness(left, top, 0, 0);
                left += 70;
                fields[x, y].Height = 32;
                fields[x, y].Width = 32;
                fields[x, y].Click += new RoutedEventHandler(field_Click);

                fields[x, y].Name = "Field_" + x + "_" + y;
                this.AddChild(fields[x, y]);


            }
            left = 20;
            top += 70;
        }
```

but this gives me the error that I cant add mutliple controls at "ContentControl"; What is the error here?

Comment: Try adding the buttons to something like a grid then do this.AddChild(grid)

Comment: You add a child to `this` which I assume is your window. Windows in WPF can have only one child. Usually people put some sort of container as that child e.g. in your case a `Grid` control. Now a `Grid` can have unlimited children. You would setup your rows and columns for the `Grid` and assign the children (buttons) to that setting the `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` attached properties on them. There are boatloads of examples on the interwebs for `Grid`s. I would suggest working through a few examples so you get a feel for WPF and how it is supposed to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Content control is `StackPanel, Grid, Canvas` etc. You need to place all of the controls inside of a content control, since `Window` or `UserControl` can only have one child control.

Xaml:

```
<StackPanel>
   <Button/>
   <Button/>
</StackPanel>
```

In your case c# code should look something like this:

```
StackPanel yourSP = new StackPanel(); // Creates a new content control.
Button button1 = new Button;          // Creates buttons.
Button button2 = new Button;
this.AddChild(yourSP);                // Adds StackPanel to your Window/UserControl
yourSP.Children.Add(button1);         // Adds buttons to content control.
yourSP.Children.Add(button2);
```

It creates a new `StackPanel` which is a content control and adds it as a child to your `Window/UserControl` afterwards you add `Buttons` to your `StackPanel`.

Please refer [here for more information](http://www.wpftutorial.net/Layout.html) regarding content controls.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way of accomplishing what you want in my opinion is to use a `UniformGrid`. The code below is untested, but it should look something like this:

```
const int squareSize = 8;
var grid = new UniformGrid { Rows = squareSize, Columns = squareSize };
for (int y = 0; y < squareSize; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < squareSize; x++)
    { 
        var btn = new Button { Height = 32, Width = 32 };
        btn.Click += field_Click;
        grid.Children.Add(btn);
        fields[x, y] = btn;
    }
}
this.AddChild(grid);
```